# SwiftUI PageViewController Indexing

Tags: xcode, swiftui, indexing, storyboard, datasource

I'm using a pageViewController on the newest version of Xcode(SwiftUI). When I try to index my datasource it says Im unable to do that because: "Cannot assign to value: 'index' is a method" and "Cannot assign value of type 'Int' to type '(Any) -> Int'"

Code:

guard let startingViewController = detailViewControllerAt(index: currentViewControllerIndex) else {
return
}
pageViewController.setViewControllers([startingViewController], direction: .forward, animated: true)
}

```
func detailViewControllerAt(index: Int) -> DataViewController? {
    if index >= dataSource.count || dataSource.count == 0 {
        return nil
    }
    
    guard let dataViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: String(describing: DataViewController.self)) as? DataViewController else {
        return nil
}
    dataViewController.index = index
    dataViewController.displayText = dataSource[index]
    
    return dataViewController
}
```

}

I'm using this video as a tutorial, there is no other code written in the project, Im 17:44 in:
https://www.google.com/search?sca_esv=597709555&sxsrf=ACQVn09NEQlIpK_V87flvqDZlCqLzjn4Gw:1705033257435&q=how+to+set+up+a+page+view+controller+for+albums&tbm=vid&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjG147t_9aDAxXQkokEHZqFBXAQ0pQJegQICRAB&biw=1920&bih=968&dpr=1#fpstate=ive&vld=cid:14bda130,vid:hIMRn_LdvOg,st:0

Any Help Would Be Greatly Appreciated

I'm a newer coder, I found a couple solutions to no avail, please help

Comment: On what line do you get the error? Assuming it is on `dataViewController.index = index`,
can you show the code for `dataViewController.index`. In particular what type is the `index`.
 The error says it is a method, is that correct?

Comment: That is correct it is a method index on the **dataViewController.index = index** line, Here is the DataViewController Code: **import UIKit                               class DataViewController: UIViewController { @IBOutlet var displayLabel: UILabel!                                   var displayText: String?                 override func viewDidLoad() {               super.viewDidLoad()                 displayLabel.text = displayText // Do any additional setup after loading the view.**

Comment: can you show the code for `dataViewController.index`. In particular what type is it. Note, edit your question and put the relevant code, well formatted in it.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding it is a cocoa touch class view controller, it supposed to hold the data for the page controller.

Comment: Here is the code for the dataViewController: `import UIKit

class DataViewController: UIViewController {
  
    @IBOutlet var displayLabel: UILabel!
    var displayText: String?
    
    `

Comment: Part 2 `override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        displayLabel.text = displayText

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }`

Comment: The Apple SwiftUI tutorial about interfacing with UIKit has a great example

Answer (score 0):

try using `dataViewController.index(ofAccessibilityElement: index)`
instead of `dataViewController.index = index`

Comment: it says expression is not assignable, functions return an immutable value